# Play: JSON Writes is not respected when class extends case class

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I have the following hierarchy of classes

```
case class A(id: String,name:String)
object A {
   implicit val reads:Reads[A] = Json.reads[A]
   implicit val writes:Writes[A] = Json.writes[A]
}

class B(id:String,name:String, val other:Int,val another:Vector[String]) extends A(id,name)
object B {
   implicit val reads:Reads[B] = Json.reads[B]
   implicit val writes:Writes[B] = Json.writes[B]

   def apply(id: String,name:String, other:Int, another:Vector[String]) = new B(id,name,other,another)
   def unapply(b: B):Option[(String,String)] = Some {(b.id,b.name,b.other,b.another)} 

}
```

the result when serialising B only includes the state of its parent class `A` and is the following:

```
{
  id:"some value",
  name: "some other value"
}
```

what should be the configuration of the `Reads` and `Writes` in order for the ones in the subclass to be respected and all the included key value pairs to be appropriately serialised. The result I expect is the following:

```
{
  id:"some value",
  name: "some other value",
  other: 4,
  another: ["a","b"]
}
```

I want no fancy custom serialisation of the key value pairs. I would only include the reads and writes in the subclass B if only the compiler did not complain that the parent class is missing read and write implicits.

Comment: It is generally discou aged to extend case classes due to some odd behavior resulting from it. Try using a trait or abstract class for your base class.

Comment: I cannot use a trait since I need arguments. If i use an abstract class I would need to create an apply and unapply method based on Play's convention. In order to create an apply method I would need some kind of constructor. What kind of constructor am I supposed to use in an abstract class? It is abstract.

Comment: From Play's docs:
The macros work for classes and traits meeting the following requirements.

* It must have a companion object having apply and unapply methods.
* The return types of the unapply must match the argument types of the apply method.
* The parameter names of the apply method must be the same as the property names desired in the JSON.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for me, since `Json.reads[B]`already complains about not having an apply method.
also if you only call `Json.toJson(new B(...))` the implicit resolution would be ambiguous.
Sorry, I just might not understand how you want your code to look like in the end.

Comment: You're right. While trying to adjust the original code I removed the apply and unapply methods.

Comment: I can't reproduce your result where it only produces a json with A's values. And I can only serialize a B with explicitly passing the Reads[B] to Json.toJson. It might be a little bit more boilerplate but having serperate case classes might be the easiest. Also A doesn't need apply/unapply since case classes already implement that.

Comment: The thing is that this is just a part of a nested structure thus I can't just pass  this to `Json.toJson` . I have to pass the entire structure which is formed from the companion objects of Bs. Could you please submit the code that works for you?

Comment: I only used your code and a Json.toJson(new B(...)) to test it. All of it would be avoided if you don't use inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [this](https://github.com/julienrf/play-json-derived-codecs) library like this

```
sealed trait A

object A {
  implicit val oformat: OFormat[A] = julienrf.json.derived.oformat(adapter = NameAdapter.snakeCase)
}

case class B(x: String, y: String) extends A {}
```

and everything works smoothly... To be honest Play's approach on working with JSONs is still quite primitive - compared to Spring for example.